# inserting date formatted with date_format(str_to_date()))

Tags: mysql

I'm putting all 2018 sundays into a table.  I got the list and have to reformat it to fit into a datetime column.
This query generates a result

```
select date_format(str_to_date("February 11 2018","%M %d %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d %I:%i");
```

so, I thought I could just put that in an insert

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `title`, `color`, `start`, `end`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Sunday', '#FFE761', 
(select date_format(str_to_date("January 14 2018","%M %d %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d %I:%i")),
 '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

But, I'm getting errors regardless of how I try to stick the date in.  I've tried removing 'select', the parens, the %I:%i.. I'm stuck.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `title`, `color`, `start`, `end`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Sunday', '#FFE761', 
(select date_format(str_to_date("January 14 2018","%M %d %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d %I:%i"),
 '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: AH, I tried yours, which had an error, which pointed me to my error: missing end parans:

Answer (score 0):

You have too many closing brackets after the format for the date.

```
INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `title`, `color`, `start`, `end`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Sunday', '#FFE761', 
(select date_format(str_to_date("January 14 2018","%M %d %Y"),"%Y-%m-%d %I:%i")), '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.